# Obtain DateTime value from a DataRow[] and pass it into var

Tags: c#, .net

I wish to insert a Date value in DataRow[] and find a DateTime value in a column. The Date value entered will be passed to a var to perform another search. But it cannot be passed, can any1 help me fix my code?

```
//Receive StartDateTime value
DataRow[] setStartDateTime = DataSet1
            .Tables["table1"]
            .Select("StartDateTime =#" + searchMonth + "/" + searchDay + "/" + searchYear + "#");

//Count PcrID rows which same row with StartDateTime
var PcrID_1 = DataSet1
            .Tables["table1"]
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Where(c => c.Field<DateTime>("StartDateTime") == setStartDateTime) /*Error occurs here: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.DateTime' and 'System.Data.DataRow[]'*/
            .Select(d => d["PcrID"]);

Pcr_1 = PcrID_1.Count();
```

Comment: read the error it said 'System.DateTime' and 'System.Data.DataRow[] you need to convert System.Data.DataRow[] to System.DateTime.

Comment: Too bad is I do not know what is the syntax for the conversion of 'System.Data.DataRow[]' to 'System.DateTime'. That's why l need some help from some expert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you filtered rows by date-time you need to apply `Select` on that bunch of rows. For example,

```
var PcrID_1 = setStartDateTime.Select(d => d["PcrID"]);
Pcr_1 = PcrID_1.Count();
```

Of course , above code doesn't make sense if all you want is the count then you can very well do that by saying

```
Pcr_1 = setStartDateTime.length;
```

Or you can do the original filtering using LINQ - for example,

```
var searchDate = new DateTime(searchYear, searchMonth, searchDay);
var PcrID_1 = DataSet1.Tables["table1"].AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(c => c.Field<DateTime>("StartDateTime") == searchDate)
                  .Select(d => d["PcrID"]);
```

---

The first and last example code actual produces enumeration of PcrID for the given date.
If you want a distinct list then you can use Distinct extension method - for example

```
 var ids = DataSet1.Tables["table1"].AsEnumerable()
                      .Where(c => c.Field<DateTime>("StartDateTime") == searchDate)
                      .Select(d => d["PcrID"]).Distinct();
```

Comment: Let's say there will be a lot PcrID in the same date, is it possible to obtain every value of PcrID which match with the Date entered?